# How to use remove button on element so it doesn't remove the ability to submit form

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to make a form where you can create different memes.

I want to be able to remove memes with a button but still be able to create more memes with the form. I know my remove button is not removing the actual item being created but I don't know how to do that. It should remove each meme respectively.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Meme Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MemeGeneratorCSS.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Make Memes</h1>
    <h3>Fill out the form to create your very own meme!</h3>
    <div class="container">
    <form action="action.php" method="POST" id= "form" >
      <div class="row">
        <label for= "memeImage" >Image URL:</label>
      </div>
      <input type = "url" name = "memeImage" id = "memeImage" placeholder = "Put your favorite image's URL here" > 
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <label for= "topText" >Text on top:</label>
      </div>
      <input type= "text" name = "topText" id= "topText" placeholder = "Place text you want to appear at the top of your image">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <label for= "bottomText" >Text on bottom:</label>
      </div>
      <input type = "text" name = "bottomText" id = "bottomText" placeholder = "Place text you want to appear at the bottom of your image">
      <br>
      <button type = "submit" id="memeButton" name="memeButton ">Create your Meme!</button>
    </form>
    <div id = textAlign>
      <p id = "log"></p>
      <div id = textOnTop></div>
      <div id = textOnBottom></div>
      </p>
    </div>
    <script src = "MemeGeneratorJS.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
let numKeys = null;
const form = 
    document.getElementById("form");
const log = 
    document.getElementById('log');
const clickButton = 
    document.getElementById('memeButton');

form.addEventListener("submit", 
    function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

const log = document.getElementById('log');
const newPic = document.getElementById("memeImage");
const textTop = document.getElementById("topText");
const textBottom = document.getElementById("bottomText");
const textOnTop = document.getElementById('textOnTop');
const textOnBottom = document.getElementById('textOnBottom');
// const meme = document.getElementById("p");

numKeys = localStorage.length; 

localStorage.setItem('newitem' + (numKeys + 1), log);
    
log.innerHTML += '<div><button type="submit" id="removeMeme" onclick="removeMeme()">Delete</button><img src="' + newPic.value + '" alt="Image" /></div>';
textOnTop.textContent += textTop.value;

textOnBottom.textContent += textBottom.value;

var btn = document.getElementById('removeMeme');
btn.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('textAlign').remove();
    this.remove();
};

form.reset();
```

Comment: That is not Java. That is javascript. They are drastically different.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this in the btn.onclick function :

```
btn.onclick = function () {
document.getElementById('textAlign').innerHTML='<p id = "log"></p> <div id = textOnTop></div> <div id = textOnBottom></div></p>';

this.remove();};
```

I think this should work because, in your code, all the HTML tags in the div were been deleted.

Comment: Thank you! This is great and works to delete the first meme created and also allows for the form to be submitted again. The only thing is if two memes are created the delete button will only work with the first meme and the second meme's delete button won't work.

Comment: I could try to solve the problem but it would require the use of an array which would change a bit you HTML code